# A new slice has nil as it's 1st value

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a simple proof-of-concept for an image resizing server in Golang. I'm new to golang, and am stuck at this frustrating issue. Maybe I haven't understood slices correctly, so please let me where I am wrong in the usage of slices.

I use `request.ParseMultipartForm()` to parse the files and any POST params sent to the server. Then, I need to convert the list of files (which are a `map[string][]*multipart.FileHeader`). I'm using the following code to do so.

```
    // convert the FileHeader map to a list of io.Readers
    images := make([]io.Reader, len(reqForm.File))
    fmt.Println(images)
    for _, fileHeaders := range reqForm.File {
        fh := fileHeaders[0]
        f, err := fh.Open()
        fmt.Printf("Converting: %v\n", f)
        if err != nil {
            writeErrorToResponse(resp, err)
            return
        }

        images = append(images, f)
    }
```

My problem is, for some reason `images` ends up having a `nil` as it's first value after being initialized by `make`. I know this because the `fmt.Println(images)` (line of code 2) prints out:

```
[<nil>]
```

I assumed that the make would return a slice with zero elements. If I do a `make([]io.Reader, 0)` instead, it works as I expect. I'm confused with this behavior and an explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: What is a POC? Do you mean proof of concept? Please try to avoid ambiguous acronyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`images := make([]io.Reader, len(reqForm.File))` creates a slice of the given length and the same capacity. When you later `append` to it, new values are put on the end.

You can fix this in two ways:

- start with a length 0, but the given capacity with `images := make([]io.Reader, 0, len(reqForm.File))`
- start with an empty slice, and allow `append` to grow it naturally. `var images []io.Reader`.

I'd choose the latter since it's slightly simpler, and replace it with the preallocated slice later if it turns out it's a bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess coming from Python, I assumed that a new slice with 1 element is still empty and appending to it would overwrite the nil value.

Comment: I'd have to disagree with choosing the uncapped slice, if you already know the size why waste memory.